# Yammer Export API token Expired

Tags: yammer

We are using Yammer Export API token to download Yammer Messages for one of our Microsoft application. From last one month, we are getting "(401) Unauthorized" error while trying to download Yammer Messages.

Could you please let us know, how to fix this error and renew Yammer API Token. Please find below error Message.

```
"System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)     at ConsoleDownloadApplication.Program.<ExportAPICall>d__9.MoveNext() line 255"
```

Comment: This question may be better answered by directly contacting yammer's customer service. Furthermore, [questions asking for: libraries, tools, or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please let me know, where and how I can contact yammer's customer service?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/yammer

Answer (score 0):

Per this page of the Yammer developer docs https://developer.yammer.com/docs/api-requests, apps can ask for a new token when their old token for a user expires. More detail is provided on the page.